# Laravel: Detect sub-controllers in nested controller routes?

Tags: php, laravel

What's the easiest way to auto-detect a nested controller? Like:

```
Route::controller('forms.*');
```

This works, but it's a bit hacky:

```
Route::any('forms/(:any)/(:any)', function($entity_type, $id){
    return Controller::call('forms.' . $entity_type . '@index', array($id));
});
```

Also, proper nested controller routes don't accept backslash arguments. Is this a bug or feature?

```
Route::controller('forms.user');
dan.com/forms/user/31 = 401
```

Comment: I would just say write them all out so you know exactly what's what. Otherwise your solution is what I'd use. Or Something like `Route::any('forms/(:any)/(:any)', 'forms.(:1)@(:2)');`

Comment: I wouldn't mind writing them out, but I still can't get arguments to work with the nested controllers. Not the way they do with regular controller routes, anyways.

Comment: What you're looking at is a requirement for HMVC that is actually available as a bundle in Laravel 3. Cross controller routing is something that standard MVC's don't do by design.